# Facing issue while running the app for ocr detection with mlkit-text-recognition v16.2.0 dependency

Tags: android, google-mlkit

E/MobileVisionBase: Error preloading model resource
com.google.mlkit.common.MlKitException: Failed to init text recognizer play-services-mlkit-text-recognition
at com.google.mlkit.vision.text.internal.zzb.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition@@16.2.0:15)
at com.google.mlkit.vision.text.internal.zzo.load(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition@@16.2.0:1)
at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.ModelResource.zza(Unknown Source:18)
at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzn.run(Unknown Source:10)
at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzp.run(com.google.mlkit:common@@17.1.1:2)
at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zze(com.google.mlkit:common@@17.1.1:4)
at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zzc(Unknown Source:8)
at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzj.run(Unknown Source:2)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zzd(Unknown Source:10)
at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzk.run(Unknown Source:2)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Failed to initialize TfLite-GMS
at m.ui.c(:com.google.android.gms.optional_mlkit_ocr_common@241017042@24.10.17 (100400-0):283)
at m.blj.a(:com.google.android.gms.optional_mlkit_ocr_common@241017042@24.10.17 (100400-0):112)
at m.at.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.optional_mlkit_ocr_common@241017042@24.10.17 (100400-0):21)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1084)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.mlkit_vision_text.zza.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition@@16.2.0:2)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.mlkit_vision_text.zzlm.zze(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition@@16.2.0:2)
at com.google.mlkit.vision.text.internal.zzb.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition@@16.2.0:13)
at com.google.mlkit.vision.text.internal.zzo.load(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition@@16.2.0:1) 
at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.ModelResource.zza(Unknown Source:18) 
at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzn.run(Unknown Source:10) 
at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzp.run(com.google.mlkit:common@@17.1.1:2) 
at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zze(com.google.mlkit:common@@17.1.1:4) 
at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zzc(Unknown Source:8) 
at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzj.run(Unknown Source:2) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644) 
at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zzd(Unknown Source:10) 
at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzk.run(Unknown Source:2) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012) 
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libmlkit_google_ocr_pipeline_gms.so" not found
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1082)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1003)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1661)
at m.ui.c(:com.google.android.gms.optional_mlkit_ocr_common@241017042@24.10.17 (100400-0):18)
at m.blj.a(:com.google.android.gms.optional_mlkit_ocr_common@241017042@24.10.17 (100400-0):112) 
at m.at.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.optional_mlkit_ocr_common@241017042@24.10.17 (100400-0):21) 
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1084)

tried with degraded the mlkit version but still no luck

Comment: Does this device have Google Play Services installed? `Failed to initialize TfLite-GMS` suggests that. When it's an emulator, you might need to select a different image.

Comment: Yes device have google play services installed.